# Is there any performance difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?

Tags: c++, include, preprocessor-directive

I understand the difference between `#include <filename>` and `#include "filename"` as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/).

Is there any performance difference between them? If yes, how do you prove the performance difference in this case? What is the best use case for each?

Comment: There is no performance difference. `#include` directives are resolved by your compiler when it compiles your code, not when your program runs.

Comment: The only performance diff is compile time which should not be a reason to choose one or the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include "filename"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Comment: The use case is normally `<>` for system headers, and `""` for user headers. The use case applies because of the way compilers generally interpret the two different types of include, YMMV.